# Hide siblings based on status column and update sibling count on "parent" sibling using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm struggling a bit with a sort of peculiar table which I want to Filter & perform some counting on.

Note: all rows are siblings but they represent parents, children and direct nodes (= they don't have a parent and just exist by themselves).

The table structure cannot be changed... we have to work with what we have.

The table has the following structure:

```
<table class="myTable">
...
<tbody>
<TR>
 <Td>Status</Td>
 <Td>Name</Td>
</TR>
<TR class="parent">
 <Td>Parent (3=>2)</Td>
 <Td>First Parent</Td>
</TR>
<TR class="child" param="ID1">
 <Td>Active</Td>
 <Td>Child 1A</Td>
</TR>
<TR class="child" param="ID1">
 <Td>Inactive</Td>
 <Td>Child 1B</Td>
</TR>
<TR class="child" param="ID1">
 <Td>Active</Td>
 <Td>Child 1C</Td>
</TR>

<TR class="parent">
 <Td>Parent (2=>1)</Td>
 <Td>Second Parent</Td>
</TR>
<TR class="child" param="ID2">
 <Td>Active</Td>
 <Td>Child 2A</Td>
</TR>
<TR class="child" param="ID2">
 <Td>Active</Td>
 <Td>Child 2B</Td>
</TR>

<TR>
 <Td>Active</Td>
 <Td>Direct Item X</Td>
</TR>
<TR>
 <Td>Inactive</Td>
 <Td>Direct Item Y</Td>
</TR>

<TR class="parent">
 <Td>Parent (2=>0)</Td>
 <Td>Third Parent</Td>
</TR>
<TR class="child" param="ID3">
 <Td>Inactive</Td>
 <Td>Child 3A</Td>
</TR>
<TR class="child" param="ID3">
 <Td>Inactive</Td>
 <Td>Child 3B</Td>
</TR>

<TR>
 <Td>Inactive</Td>
 <Td>Direct Item Z</Td>
</TR>
...
</tbody>
</table>
```

The rows can represent parents, children or direct items in any order.

All children always directly follow the parent row.  The list of children ends when there is a new parent or a direct element in a following row.

All children of the same parent have a parameter with the same ID. However that ID is nowhere present on the parent row. We could only pick it from the first child row following a parent row if needed.

A parent contains the number of associated children in parentheses after the string "Parent " in the status column.

"Item row" means either a child row OR a direct item row, so no parent rows.

**what I am trying to accomplish:**

1. i want to hide all item rows (children and direct items) that have a status different from "Active"
2. I want to update the child count in the parentheses of the parent row to only count visible children = those with status "Active"
3. I want to completely hide parent rows that do not have any "Active" children

Hiding the item rows is easy as I can simply do

```
$(".myTable > tbody > tr").not("*:contains('Active')").css("display", "none");
```

What I can't figure out though is how tackle points 2 and 3 from above.

Update: also please not the table is actually a lot more complex than the structure outlined above and is partially updated with Ajax, complex JavaScript logic operates on the table, etc. So rewriting the whole table is not anoption and it has to be done by amending the table using jQuery.

Also I cannot load any additional Frameworks/ libraries. jQuery it is.

Comment: I'd: 1) read the entire table into an array 2) accomplish 1,2,3 but with the array 3) update the table based on the array

Comment: Hi Chris, the table is a lot more complex than this and gets updated with Ajax components etc. It really has to be done by amending the table via jQuery. Thanks for your reply though!

Comment: No it hasn't; you can simply write a function that does all this again after new data was inserted. No matter how you slice this, parsing the table into a more suitable data structure will always make your life easier. If you don't believe, feel free to discard my advice.

Comment: Hi Chris, sorry, but there are a gazillion jscript functions operating on the table. Rewriting the table is simply not an option in this usecase, although I do agree that - if it is feasible - it is for sure a good approach. Thanks & Regards Fabian

Comment: I’m sure there’s a dupe of this, and @ChrisG’s comment is ultimately the best long term solution. ``$(‘.parent’).each((index, el) => $(el).toggle($(el).nextUntil(‘:not(.child)’).length).find(‘td:first”).text(`Parent (${$(el).nextUntil(‘:not(.child)’).length}`) );``

Comment: You don't understand. It doesn't matter how many functions are operating on the table. And I didn't suggest to rewrite it. What I suggested is, based on your statement about the table structure, that in order to achieve what you want to achieve, you need to write a function which a) reads in the table in its current state and puts it in an array b) performs ops on the array c) updates the DOM table based on the array. Hope it's clear now.

Comment: Hi @HereticMonkey , thank you for you answer ! This looks great - I've put it into a jsFiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/hx40ek7d/5 but it doesn't quite work yet .. it hides all the parent rows and it also seems to count all children as opposed to only the visible ones (i.e. the ones with status "Active". Do you have a hint on how to get this last bit working as well ? Thank you!

Comment: Hi @HereticMonkey, I managed to correct the counting of children by doing


`$('.parent').each((index, el) => $(el).find("td:first").text('Parent (${$(el).nextUntil(":not(.child)").has("*:visible").length})') );`

however I couln't figure out yet how to conditionally hide the parent rows based on the number of contained active children being > 0

see here: https://jsfiddle.net/hx40ek7d/7/

Comment: one way would be to append another `$('.parent:contains("Parent (0)")').toggle();`... not sure though if that is really the best approach ;)

Comment: As far as I can see, there are no parent rows that do not have active children in your sample HTML.

Comment: Hi @hereticMonkey I have added that explicit example which was only textually described.  The main remaining issue though is that we only have a limited jquery available on the page and can't use nextUntil() ...   can we rewrite that part to get along without nextUntil()?   FYI this is supposed to run on the inventory management table in Amazon Seller Central in case you have access to that.